# User friendly date input

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have to code program, which will asks user about some data and then will print some text with this data.
Below is just piece of code (which works), there are others variables too.

```
class Student
{
    static public DateTime birthDay;

    public void GetStudentInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter student's birth date (as mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        birthDay = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void PrintStudentData(ref DateTime birthDay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student was born in {0}", birthDay.ToString("d"));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student newStudent = new Student();
        newStudent.GetStudentInformation();
        newStudent.PrintStudentData(ref Student.birthDay);
        Console.ReadKey()
    }
}
```

When I'm asking about birthday I need only date, not exactly time.
There are questions:

1. How to change that input date by user would be in other format than *mm/dd/yyyy*?
2. How I would operate on output format date? So it wouldn't be *yyyy-dd-mm* but *dd/mm/yyyy* or *dd.mm.yyyy*?

I want to add I'm really beginner in C# and tried some code with `CultureInfo`, `ParseExact`, `TryParse`, and modyfing output string with `{0:'dd/mm/yyyy'}`.

Comment: First two suggestions: 1) don't mix code for the interface and data representation in your clasess (as they are you won't be able to reuse them in an enviroment without terminal / console, ej: web) 2) Totally use CultureInfo unless it doens't fit your needs. Now, I'm unsure on the question, do you want configurable date format? And what does "user freandly" mean here anyway? Edit: I'm assuming you already tested the methods you mention. [You can edit your question to add clarifications]

Comment: @Theraot - I don't get your first point at all. What's wrong with this code? Should I create another class for some data?
Yea, I tested this program many times.
My second question is about output string. Program prints 'Student was born in yyyy-dd-mm', and I would switch it to, for example, 'Student was born in dd/mm/yyyy'.

Comment: It is not wrong. I may have been too authoritative in my phrasing. I'll put it this way: there are many ways to do a task, some are more efficient and some more reusable, and they don't align. You may grow to value reusability over efficiency. So, I suggest to separate UI from data representation. Does the current code misbehave because it lacks that? No, it should work fine. Also, this code may never be migrated, so its reusability may not matter. Still, it is a good to accustom yourself to for when you need it. When? when you want same core multiple UI. Meanwhile you can forget what I said.

Comment: @Theraot this is obviously an student homework, I'm really sure he will never reuse it (unless he repeats grades)

Comment: @Theraot, as Gusman said - it's just homework from edx course, but thanks for advice, I will try remember this :D

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexac) is a good way to do it.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format, culture-specific
>   format information, and style. The format of the string representation
>   must match the specified format exactly. The method returns a value
>   that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

```
DateTime birthDay;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out birthDay)
{
    // Your input string can (and will) be parsed with MM/dd/yyyy format.
}
else
{
    // Invalid format or value.
}
```

By the way, I changed your `mm` to `MM` because `mm` specifier is for minutes but `MM` specifier is for months.

For your questions;

> How to change that input date by user would be in other format than
>   mm/dd/yyy?

You *can't*. This *might* create a lot of ambiguous situations like what is the format of `01/02/2016`? Is it `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`? This totally depends on where you live and which culture settings you use.

> How I would operate on output format date? So it wouldn't be
>   yyyy-dd-mm but dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy?

With output, if you mean the `Console.WriteLine` part, this [The `"d"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) uses [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern) of your `CurrentCulture` settings where you run this code. That means the output format depends on the current culture settings. If this property has `dd/MM/yyyy`, you will be fine. If it is not, you should format it with customd date format specifiers like;

```
Console.WriteLine("Student was born in {0}", 
                  birthDay.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Yea, I know it would be misunderstanding, this is why I added into my code '(as mm/dd/yyyy)' and same thing I could add to another 'system'. Really thanks for answer :D

Answer (score 0):

This let user input in format `day/month/year` and output as `dd.MM.yyyy`

```
static void Main()
{
    Student newStudent = new Student();
    newStudent.GetStudentInformation();
    newStudent.PrintStudentData(ref Student.birthDay);
    Console.ReadKey();

    logEnd();
}
class Student
{
    static public DateTime birthDay;

    public void GetStudentInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter student's birth date as day/month/year");

        string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy",
                "dd/MM/yy", "dd/M/yy", "d/M/yy", "d/MM/yy"};

        while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), formats,
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
             System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
             out birthDay))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your input is incorrect. Please input again.");
        }

        // User input correct, birthDay can now be used

    }
    public void PrintStudentData(ref DateTime birthDay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student was born in {0}", birthDay.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    }
}
```