# Combining ViewStates in C# OR combining generic lists in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following two **ViewStates** 1 storing all the start dates and the other storing all the End dates of a particular event:

```
private List<DateTime> SelectedStartDates
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["SelectedStartDates"] != null)
                return (List<DateTime>)ViewState["SelectedStartDates"];

            return new List<DateTime>();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["SelectedStartDates"] = value;
        }
    }

    private List<DateTime> SelectedEndDates
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["SelectedEndDates"] != null)
                return (List<DateTime>)ViewState["SelectedEndDates"];

            return new List<DateTime>();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["SelectedEndDates"] = value;
        }
    }
```

**Question:**

Is there a way in which I can have a combined List of values stored in these two ViewStates in the following manner:

```
List[0] = first value of Start date

List[1] = first value of End date

List[2] = second value of Start date

List[3] = second value of End date

.

.

.
```

and so on till the last value of both the Lists in the **ViewState**.

The other way I can think of is to combine the **Generic List** returned by the **ViewState** again in a manner as mentioned above.

Also, I would like to keep the duplicate values in the combined list

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: Is number of items in two list equal?

Comment: Yes. they are exactly equal... Also, I would like to keep the duplicate values as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
List<DateTime> combine = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i < SelectedStartDates.Count; i++)
{
    combine.Add(SelectedStartDates[i]);
    combine.Add(SelectedEndDates[i]);
}
```

If two input lists is `List<string>` type, and each items in these lists are valid `DateTime` (for example, it item is inserted by `(DateTime).ToString()` function), you can use:

```
List<string> SelectedStartDates = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
List<string> SelectedEndDates = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

List<DateTime> combine = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i < SelectedStartDates.Count; i++)
{
    combine.Add(DateTime.Parse(SelectedStartDates[i]));
    combine.Add(DateTime.Parse(SelectedEndDates[i]));
}
```

You you're not sure about if a string is valid `DateTime` format or not, you can use `DateTime.TryParse`.

You can read about:

- DateTime.Parse;
- DateTime.ParseExact;
- DateTime.TryParse;
- [DateTime.TryParseExact (my working answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35683158/1560697)

Comment: Your solution is resulting in the following error: "The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>.Add(System.DateTime) has some invalid arguments`"

Comment: I had already changed it before posting the error. It is DateTime

Comment: Because your two list is `List<string>`. Is these strings are in `DateTime` format?

Comment: it is impossible to have that error. You can search for that error in internet.

Comment: Just for the sake of knowledge, may I know how to solve this issue if two Lists are of type string and after combining I want to convert it to single string of type DateTime ? Is it even possible? If yes then please add to your answer.

Comment: I tried using DateTime.Parse to convert the string to DateTime

Comment: It is throwing an `InvalidCastException` on my return statement. Does Generic List not accept List<DateTime> ?

Comment: No, it accept. What you're trying to cast from and to?

Comment: I was using the wrong way to store values in the `ViewState` like this: `DateTime txtStartDate = DateTime.Parse(tbs.Text);    DateTime txtEndDate = DateTime.Parse(tbe.Text);` instead of List<DateTime/string>. How foolish.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it like you said, up until the minimum count of both lists, then you can use the Zip() method. ie:

```
SelectedStartDates.Zip( SelectedEndDates, (s, e) => new 
   {Start = s, End = e});
```

Comment: This function doesn't output to the sequence in which I would like to have my output as mentioned in the question. This method is however interesting

Comment: You are right, I did't pay attention that you wanted a flat list.

Comment: Yep. But still I have something to gain from your answer. I wasn't aware of this `.Zip` method and hopefully this will help me someday in future. Thanks.